# Wifi EAP auth at login to network account on OsX and Win

Tags: authentication, networking, wifi, account

i'm trying to improve the security of our network by disabling our legacy WPA wifi aps. All account are on the network so computers needs network connection to authenticate users.we have now only EAP-MSCHAP V2 scure Wifi (user/password auth), so laptop are not on network when user is not logged in... Our policy is to avoid storing auth information on the computer (pass). So my question is : is there a way to authenticate user on the EAP wifi and then on the domain ?
Laptop are Macs (10.6 to 10.8) and Windows (XP/7).

Thanking by advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

what you would like to achieve is usually done by using 802.1X: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X.

A possible solution could look like this:

- Each client/notebook (not the user) has a certificate from a common trsuted source (a PKI)
- The client request a connection on your 802.1X Access Point who forwards the Request to a defined authentication service (usually a wireless controller and subsequently a radius server). This can be done by EAP protocol for example.
- Depending on the authentication result, the client can connect.

In this scenario a certificate is used so that the client/notebook can connect before any windows login happened.

Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have already set up a EAP wifi with password auth for user. So i was wondering if we can use it at login without the need of certificate.So auth steps would be :
1 - Login prompt --> user type login/pass
2 - Wifi logon to Radius server with user credential
3 - Os log on to the netowork to authorize user session login.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible. You can either authenticate the client (which needs to be done by Cert) or the user (which will only happen after windows login).